# Parse NVP from Json result in AJAX

Tags: json, ajax

I'm certain this question has been asked and answered many times but none of the examples that I can find work in my case. The picture below is a screen capture of the jason result that I receive in AJAX. It's almost as simple as you can get. There is one record and all I want to do is parse out 3 fields.

Here is what the ajax looks like where I was able to create the output.

```
 }).done(function (data) {
var d = JSON.parse(data);
alert(d);
```

You can see from the screen capture which I got by using alert(d) that the data is there. I have tried many different formats to try and get a single field but they all return undefined. Here are some samples that I have tried

```
alert(d.EntryNum)
alert(d[0].EntryNum)
alert(d[0]["EntryNum"]
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Returned Data]

Comment: d = JSON.parse(d); 
alert(d.EntryNum); will do

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's it. I won't even bother asking why I need to parse it twice, but, if it works, it works.

Comment: For completeness, I will add the return code from my Controller. The object described here (lvm.Entity) is a simple class defined in c#.  'string jason = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lvm.Entity);
            return Json(jason);

Comment: My next question should be "How to you mark code in comments, because as you can see from above example, I don't know how.